# How to schedule SPSS Modeler streams to run automatically?

Tags: spss, spss-modeler

I'm very new to SPSS Modeler and previously used SAS Guide & Miner to schedule batches and scheduled runs.

We currently manually run streams weekly then export them into Excel to use for reporting.

Is there any way to schedule these streams to run automatically?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

ModelerBatch can be used only if you have the SPSS Modeler Server installed. I use the task scheduler from Windows but first you have to write an archive .bat

**Example of .bat:**
**call "C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Modeler\18.1\bin\clemb.exe" -stream "E:\path\stream.str" -execute -log "E:\path\stream.str.log"**

The .bat will call SPSS Modeler and the stream selected. After that, you can schedule the task (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446802(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

there is a product called ModelerBatch which could meet your demand precisely. Just check it on google.