# SPSS stream executing with python

Tags: spss-modeler

I need help with script in python to run stream in SPSS. Now I am using with code to export data into Excel file and it works. But this code is required one manual step before exporting data to Excel file.

```
stream = modeler.script.stream()  **- geting stream in SPSS;**
output1 = stream.findByType("excelexport", "1") **- then searching Excel file with name "1";**
results = [] **- then run all stream;**
output1.run(results) **- but here I need to press button to finish execution(Have a look screenshots);** 
output1 = stream.findByType("excelexport", "2") **- this the next step!**
results = []
output1.run(results)
```

I would like to fully automate stream. Please, help me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You mention some screenshots, but there are none. Maybe you forgot to add them.

Comment: Yep, But I cannot attached it.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you only using the legacy script. I have several export excel nodes in my streams and they are saved according to the month and year of reference.

set Excel_1.full_filename = "\\PATH"><"*TO*"><".xlsx" execute Excel_1[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGwzE.jpg)

Take a look in the image because the stackoverflow is messing with the written code.

And to fully automatize, you have also to set all the passwords in the initial nodes, example:

set Database.username = "TEST"

set Database.password = "PASSWORD"*

Answer (score -1):

On the stream properties window -> Exection tab  have you selected the 'Run this script' on stream execution??

If you make this selection you can run the stream and produce your output without even opening SPSS Modeler User Interface(via Modelerbatch).

Comment: Modeler Batch it's an optional feature and in order to schedule without it you can check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46486246/how-to-schedule-spss-modeler-streams-to-run-automatically